# Understanding CGAfflineTransform in the context of Rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on a few experiments to learn gestures and animations in iOS. Creating a Tinder-like interface is one of them. I am following this guide: http://guti.in/articles/creating-tinder-like-animations/

I understand the changing of the position of the image, but don't understand the rotation. I think I've pinpointed my problem to not understanding CGAfflineTransform. Particularly, the following code:

```
CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xDistance / 320, 1);
CGFloat rotationAngle = (CGFloat) (2 * M_PI * rotationStrength / 16);
CGFloat scaleStrength = 1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / 4;
CGFloat scale = MAX(scaleStrength, 0.93);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle);
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
self.draggableView.transform = scaleTransform;
```

Where are these values and calculations, such as: 320, 1-fabs(strength) /  4 , .93, etc, coming from? How do they contribute to the eventual rotation?

On another note, Tinder seems to use a combination of swiping and panning. Do they add a swipe gesture to the image, or do they just take into account the velocity of the pan?

Answer (score 0):

That code has a lot of [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants), most of which are likely chosen because they resulted in something that "looked good". This can make it hard to follow. It's not so much about the actual transforms, but about the values used to create them.

Let's break it down, line by line, and see if that makes it clearer.

---

```
CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xDistance / 320, 1);
```

The value `320` is likely assumed to be the width of the device (it was the portrait width of all iPhones until the 6 and 6+ came out).

This means that `xDistance / 320` is a factor of how far along the the x axis (based on the name `xDistance)` that the user has dragged. This will be 0.0 when the user hasn't dragged any distance and 1.0 when the user has dragged 320 points.

`MIN(xDistance / 320, 1)` Takes the smallest value of the dragged distance factor and 1). This means that if the user drags further than 320 points (so that the distance factor would be larger than 1, the rotation strength would never be larger than 1.0. It doesn't protect agains negative values (if the user dragged to the left, xDistance would be a negative value, which would always be smaller than 1. However, I'm not sure if the guide accounted for that (since 320 is the full width, not the half width.

So, the first line is a factor between 0 and 1 (assuming no negative values) of how much rotation should be applied.

---

```
CGFloat rotationAngle = (CGFloat) (2 * M_PI * rotationStrength / 16);
```

The next line calculates the actual angle of rotation. The angle is specified in radians. Since 2π is a full circle (360°), the rotation angle is ranging from 0 and 1/16 of a full circle (22.5°). Th value `1/16` is likely chosen because it "looked good".

The two lines together means that as the user drags further, the view rotates more.

---

```
CGFloat scaleStrength = 1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / 4;
```

From the variable name, it would look like it would calculate how much the view should scale. But it's actually calculating what scale factor the view should have. A scale of 1 means the "normal" or unscaled size. When the rotation strength is 0 (when the xDistance is 0), the scale strength will be 1 (unscaled). As rotation strength increase, approaching 1, this scale factor approaches 0.75 (since that's 1 - 1/4).

`fabsf` is simply the floating point absolute value (`fabsf(-0.3)` is equal to `0.3`)

---

```
CGFloat scale = MAX(scaleStrength, 0.93);
```

On the next line, the actual scale factor is calculated. It's simply the largest value of the scaleStrength and 0.93 (scaled down to 93%). The value `0.93` is completely arbitrary and is likely just what the author found appealing.

Since the scale strength ranges from 1 to 0.75 and the scale factor is never smaller than 0.93, the scale factor only changes for the first third of the xDistance. All scale strength values in the next two thirds will be smaller than 0.93 and thus won't change the scale factor.

---

With the scaleFactor and rotationAngle calculated as above, the view is first rotated (by that angle) and then scaled down (by that scale factor).

### Summary

So, in short. As the view is dragged to the right (as xDistance approaches 320 points), The view linearly rotates from 0° to 22.5° over the full drag and scales from 100% to 93% over the first third of the drag (and then stays at 93% for the remainder of the drag gesture).